# Getting all parameters from URL in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

In a Zend application with an example url like this one:

http://example.com/Controller/action/42

Is there any convenient way to retreive that last parameter? (The "42")

```
$this->_request->getParams();
```

won't work since it only retreives name value pairs.

Comment: Have you tried using `$this->_getAllParams()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for [**Zend_Controller_Router**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard).

> Zend_Controller_Router_Route is the standard framework route. It combines ease of use with flexible route definition. Each route consists primarily of URL mapping (of static and dynamic parts (variables)) and may be initialized with defaults as well as with variable requirements.

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':controller/:action/:id',
    array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'id'         => 0
    ),
    array('id' => '\d+') // Makes sure :id is an int
);

$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
$router->addRoute('myRouteName', $route);
```

Answer (score 2):

its not valid zf url

url is usually consist of

> /controller/action/id/value/id2/value2/....../idN/valueN

and then can read all of these params together :

> $this->_getAllParams()
>
> $this->_request->getParams();

or by its ID using your own

> $this->_request->getParam("id");
>
> $this->_getParam("id")

Comment: This is not entirely true. It is not a STANDART ZF url, but it certainly is valid!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @adlawson, state you need to create a route that accept the parameter. By doing this you also give a name to this parameter. The code @adlawson proposed is good enough:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
':controller/:action/:id',
array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action'     => 'index',
    'id'         => 0
),
array('id' => '\d+') // Makes sure :id is an int
);

$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
$router->addRoute('myRouteName', $route);
```

Then, the simplest way, in the controller, to retrieve the value of the `id` from your url `http://example.com/Controller/action/42` is the following :

```
public function indexAction () {
    ...
    $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
    ...
}
```